# WSO2AM log mediator exception in rest service

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I use a global outgoing log mediator so as to get the full logging message when calling a web service.
When a client uses a SOAP web service everything is in order.
When the client calls for a REST web service , an exception occurs, and the response is a runtime error.

Is there something i can do about it, other than making the mediator per service and not global?

this is the mediator definition

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="WSO2AM--Ext--Out">
<log level="full">
    <property name="ParentID:" expression="get-property('parentID')"/>
    <property name="ActualRemoteAddress:" expression="get-property('client')"/>
    <property name="AuthHeader:" expression="get-property('AuthHeader')"/>
</log>
```

And this is the beginning of the exception

```
    ERROR - RelayUtils Error while building Passthrough stream
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,11]
Message: Not in an object
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.toXml(JsonUtil.java:278)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonBuilder.processDocument(JsonBuilder.java:35)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:138)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:135)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:100)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:72)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:155)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleResponse(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:320)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:86)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:52)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:295)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:529)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:251)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,11]
Message: Not in an object
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.hasNext(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:449)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.next(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:456)
    at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(StreamReaderDelegate.java:88)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: Can you activate the wire logs and update your question with the new logs?

Comment: This is the output with the wire and headers log enabled

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r7oeodwjawhehwu/wire.log

Comment: when you call the service using a rest client the error is due to this line: [2016-05-09 16:49:56,437] DEBUG - wire >> ""Hello, me"" you are not sending an xml object, just a text....try to capture the same when you are using a soapclient to compare both messages

Comment: I do not understand why it is imperative to send an xml object. 

When i create soap web services, i choose to reply with an xml object.

When i create rest services i choose to reply with a json object. 
It should be valid. If not is there a way to discriminate mediators, only for SOAP web services?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using content aware mediator(e.g logmediator) gateway will build the payload in to soap format. This is done by messagebuilders defined in the axis2.xml. According to the content type of payload , correct messagebuilder will be chosen.

In your wire log, gateway gets a payload from backend with content-type -application/json. But payload("Hello, me") is not in actual json format. So builder related to that is unable to parser the payload

```
[2016-05-09 16:49:56,433] DEBUG - wire >> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-09 16:49:56,433] DEBUG - wire >> "Date: Mon, 09 May 2016 13:48:10 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-09 16:49:56,433] DEBUG - wire >> "Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-09 16:49:56,433] DEBUG - wire >> "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.16[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-09 16:49:56,435] DEBUG - wire >> "Content-Length: 11[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-09 16:49:56,435] DEBUG - wire >> "Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-09 16:49:56,435] DEBUG - wire >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-09 16:49:56,435] DEBUG - wire >> **"Content-Type: application/json**[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-09 16:49:56,435] DEBUG - wire >> "[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-09 16:49:56,437] DEBUG - wire >> **""Hello, me""**
```